# Sending different worksheets in a workbook to different emails + CC with Outlook Signature

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I have a rang of emails on each worksheet in a workbook, I want to send the worksheets with the body of a Subject, message body and signature to the email addresses on the worksheet.

Subject is working fine, but the body of the message and Signature are not.
Below is my VBA code.
Please, i really need your help.
Thanks a lot.

```
Sub Mail_every_Worksheet()
    Dim sh As Worksheet
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
    On Error Resume Next
        If sh.Range("g1").Value Like "*@*" Then
            sh.Copy
            ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sh.Name, 56
            ActiveWorkbook.SendMail ActiveSheet.Range("g1").Value, _
                sh.Name & " Data"

            Kill ActiveWorkbook.FullName
            ActiveWorkbook.Close False
        End If
    Next sh
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlert = False
End Sub
```

Please, i really need your help.
Thanks so much.

Comment: Where did you define your email body messages and signature in the code?

Comment: Hi Alex,  I actually dont know how to do that. Can you help me please?

Comment: Hi, did the answer below solve it or you are still missing pieces?  If so what are they? Thanks-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Guess here's what you are looking for (in case you are using OUTLOOK):

```
Sub Mail_every_Worksheet()
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set Oapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set itm = Oapp.createitem(0)

SigString = Environ("username") & "\Microsoft\Signatures\XXXX.htm" ' this is where your Outlook signture being saved, yours might be different from my path

If Dir(SigString) <> "" Then
    Signt = GetBoiler(SigString)
Else
    Signt = ""
End If

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
For Each sh In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
On Error Resume Next
    If sh.Range("g1").Value Like "*@*" Then
        sh.Copy
        ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs sh.Name, 56
        With itm
        .Subject = sh.Name & " Data"
        .to = ActiveSheet.Range("g1").Value
        .cc = "your cc email address"
        .body = "here is the body" & Signt
        .Attachments.Add (sh.Name & ".xls")
        .send
        End With

        Kill ActiveWorkbook.FullName
        ActiveWorkbook.Close False
    End If
Next sh
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.DisplayAlert = False
End Sub

Function GetBoiler(ByVal sFile As String) As String
Dim fso As Object
Dim ts As Object
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ts = fso.GetFile(sFile).OpenAsTextStream(1, -2)
GetBoiler = ts.readall
ts.Close
End Function
```

I am not sure if you needs attachment and if you will need to save the workbook with different name each time it finds an email to be sent

Comment: Alex, Thanks a lot. I still have issues with this. maybe i need to ask the question again.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help, I really appreciate. Please, here is my question again. I have several worksheets in a workbook, I also have equal amount of email addresses. I need to send these worksheets to the emails. I have successful done the attaching and sending aspect with my above code, what's left is to add my outlook signature and message body. Alex'code brings up the mail, without the attachment and doesn't send it automatically. (Alex, I appreciate what you've done, thanks a lot). can you please help out? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, that above code should send the mail automatically.  I will edit the code to remove .display and add .attachment to the code soon

Comment: Hi, I have edited the code and it should works fine now.  Also for the signature location in case you cannot find it:
**Windows XP:**  
C:\Documents and Settings\%username%\Application Data\Microsoft\Signatures  
**Windows Vista, Windows 7 and Windows 8:**  
C:\Users\%username%\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Signatures

Answer (score 0):

If the answer by Alex doesn't work for you, a not so elegant solution would be to record a macro using the workbook and do what you are trying to do. Look at the vba code of the macro and make the necessary adjustments to automate it.

Comment: Thanks a lot men. this was very helpful. Sorry for the late response. i really appreciated it. Thumbs Up